# Launching a Published Web Site

Tags: visual-studio-2005, publishing

When on my local machine from VS2005, I publish my web site to a given folder.  How do I then launch that published version of my web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create new WebSite, map it's content on your directory and so on.Also you need to configure external access to your site.